# Pegar apenas o nome do usuário no AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Com esse código, eu trago tudo, Dominio/User.

```
ViewBag.User = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Gostaria de trazer apenas o nome do usuário. Posso pegar tudo isso, e pegar tudo que vem após a barra "/" e trabalhar com ele, mas acho isso meio Gambi. Gostaria de saber se há como trazer direto apenas o nome, senão irei pelo caminho acima(gambi).

Comment: Não vejo como gambiarra. Você quer apenas parte da informação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código abaixo (rodei em uma aplicação console) faz o `split` que você precisa e retorna o usuário:

```
using System.Security.Principal;

string user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1].Trim();
Console.WriteLine("Usuário: " + user);
Console.Read();
```

Segue código completo da aplicação console:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1].Trim();
            Console.WriteLine("Usuário: " + user);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Na mosca, Tiago.